# MongoDB- arrays from aggregation result

Tags: mongodb

I have the following MongoDB query:

```
db.my_collection.aggregate([
{
    $group: {"_id":"$day", count: { $sum: "$myValue" }
}}])
```

It returns the following result:

```
{
    "_id" : ISODate("2020-02-10T00:00:00.000+01:00"),
    "count" : 10
},
{
    "_id" : ISODate("2020-02-01T00:00:00.000+01:00"),
    "count" : 2
}
```

Is it possible to make two arrays from this result as below?

```
 {
    "days": [ISODate("2020-02-10T00:00:00.000+01:00"), ISODate("2020-02-01T00:00:00.000+01:00")],
    "values": [10, 2]
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, just add another `$group` stage:

```
db.my_collection.aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            "_id": "$day", count: {$sum: "$myValue"}
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            "_id": null,
            days: {$push: "$_id"},
            values: {$push: "$count"}
        }
    }
])
```